# which configuration is good for mac os x capitan?

Tags: ios

i am decided to buy mac book with capitan os .anye one suggest me which processor is suitable for developement ie. i3 or i5 or any other.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this question can't give you an authoritative answer, as there will be many different opinions as to what kind of machine is best for your personal development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faster is better :) I recommend i7 for development. Also remember about at least 8GB of RAM.

I have rMBP 15" Late 2013 with i7 and 16GB of RAM and it's very suitable for development for sure. But sometimes I see high CPU usage during compilation and some heavy application startups. I wouldn't go for i5 not to mention i3.